# How to position text correctly in LibGDX?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, resolution, resolution-independence

Currently I am using the following calculation to calculate the font scale resolution independent:

```
fontScale = ( Gdx.graphics.getDensity() / BaseDensity ) * (( (float)Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / (float)BaseResolutionWidth ) / (Gdx.graphics.getDensity() / BaseDensity) );
```

And I am using the following code to position my fonts relatively to one another:

```
font.draw(batch, glyphLayout, UniX(0.5f) - w * 0.5f, UniY(0.23f + 0.04f * scale) - h * 0.5f);
```

I am totally confused. The texts get displayed inside of each other on my 8 inch tablet, but they are alligned perfectly correct on my phone.

How should I correctly position this resolution independent?

Comment: Not an answer to your problem but you're calculation for fontScale looks to cancel itself out. If you look at the alegbra doesn't it end up just being Gdx.graphics.getWidth / BaseResolutionWidth ?

Comment: Yes it is. I managed to find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am using my App strictly in portrait mode, I am using the following aspect ratio. This seems to work flawlessly cross my devices (phones & tablets).

```
aspectRatio = ( Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / Gdx.graphics.getWidth() );
fontScale = ( ( Gdx.graphics.getDensity() / BaseDensity ) * aspectRatio );
```